# How can I display multiple action errors on multiple lines in Struts2?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a Struts2 page where I need to display 2 Action Warnings (which are essentially Errors with a flag set): 1 every time the page loads, and another depending on a property of the page.

The code I'm using for adding the action messages:

```
addActionWarning(getText(MessageKeys.WARN_PROJECTSTREAM_NOT_SAFE_DELETE));
AddProjectStreamDependencyService addProjectStreamDependencyService = (AddProjectStreamDependencyService) ServiceFactory
.getInstance().createService(AddProjectStreamDependencyService.class);
isUsedByList = addProjectStreamDependencyService.getProjectStreamDependencies(oid,
AddProjectStreamDependencyService.DEPENDENCY_TYPE_IS_USED_BY);
if(!isUsedByList.isEmpty()){
    addActionWarning(getText(MessageKeys.WARN_PROJECTSTREAM_IS_USED_BY_DELETE));
}
```

The jsp code for this page (note that this is imported by every page, so I can't alter this easily):

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test='${! empty actionErrors || ! empty actionWarnings}'>
        <s:actionerror id="globalError" cssClass="globalError" escape="false"/>
  </c:when>
  <c:when test='${! empty actionMessages}'>
        <s:actionmessage id="globalError" cssClass="globalInfo" escape="false"/>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <span id="globalError" class="globalError">&nbsp;</span>  
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

This results in the following message displayed:

```css
.globalWarning, .globalWarningDiff {
    color: #ef4121;
}
.globalInfo, .globalWarning, .globalError, .globalInfoDiff, .globalWarningDiff, .globalErrorDiff {
    font-size: 11px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<span id="globalError" class="globalWarning">
    warning: <span>This will also delete historical Project Stream information <br>like Level Requests, Builds, Deploys, etc...</span>    warning: <span>This Project Stream is still used as a Dependency by other Project Streams.</span> </span>
```

As you can see, the second message is on the same line as the first, which looks somewhat sloppy. I have tried fixing this using a Decorator method:

```
public Collection<String> getActionErrors() {
    return decorateToStringMethod(super.getActionErrors());
}

protected static Collection<String> decorateToStringMethod(Collection<String> c) {
    return new ArrayList<String>(c) {
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.util.AbstractCollection#toString()
         */
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return StringUtils.join(this, "<br />");
        }
    };      
}
```

However, this doesn't fix the issue: it still shows on the same line.

Is there a way to display multiple action errors on the same line?

Comment: Add return back tag to JSP.

Comment: @RomanC Could you please clarify what you mean by that? I have no idea what you mean by "Add return back tag to JSP".

Comment: It's just a clue why your code isn't working, you don't know how the code is written to the response, so you have to examine the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching through my project source code, I found a Freemarker template where a `<#list>` was used to iterate over the elements. I edited this template to include `<#sep><br /></#sep>` so it uses `<br />` as a separator. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for the version of Freemarker my project uses (we use 2.3.19, list builtins were added in 2.3.23).

As an alternative, I ended up using `<#if item_has_next><br /></#if>`, which was available in my version. This has solved the issue. Thanks to Roman C for suggesting to check the template.